# Flutter: blocprovider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am new to flutter and i wanted to implement a simple Login screen using BLoc. There is no build error but in runtime the following error is received

"blocprovider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type LoginBloc"

My Code

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   State<LoginForm> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
_onLoginButtonPressed() {
  BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(
    LoginButtonPressed(
      username: _usernameController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
    ),
  );
}

return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'username'),
            controller: _usernameController,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'password'),
            controller: _passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed:
                state is! LoginInProgress ? _onLoginButtonPressed : null,
            child: Text('Login'),
          ),
          Container(
            child: state is LoginInProgress
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you "provide" the `LoginBloc` in a widget above `LoginForm`?

This error means that there is no parent widget referencing a created `LoginBloc`.

If you don't you'll need to have:

```
BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
  create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
  builder: (context, state) {
    // LoginForm can now use `BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context)`
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `LoginForm` is under `LoginBloc` widget tree from dev tools. May be you are using `Navigator.push()` from the `AuthPage` to open new login form. If you are doing like this, then `loginForm` will be rendered as a new page again without `LoginPage` as a parent. So try to keep `LoginForm`  under `LoginScreen`.

Your Widget tree should look like below:

```
--LoginScreen
   --LoginBloc
     --LoginForm
```

And also make sure that you created LogicBloc as @jack said in first comment:

```
BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
  create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
  builder: (context, state) {
    // LoginForm can now use `BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context)`
  }
)
```